# IONIC 3: API POST error

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, ionic3

Refer image: [image: Error in network console]

I get the following error in console while I make POST request for logging user in.

```
1. OPTIONS http://192.192.9.175:4001/api/users/user-login 404 (NotFound)
2. Failed to load http://192.192.9.175:4001/api/users/user-login: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.
```

The backend is built in .NET MVC. After making login request, I also checked in the network tab that I get response headers as

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Content-Length: 0
```

What am I doing wrong here? I also attempted appending headers to POST request in HTTP call but in vain.

Comment: You need to check the path -- api/users/user-login-- whether user-login is present inside the folder's mentioned on the server.

Comment: @Saniyasyedqureshi If I make request to the same API URL via POSTMAN, I get no error.

Comment: I guess the issue is with the method then. Request Method Should be POST.

Answer (score 1):

check if the parameters are being passed as its post and if your passing , then you can check whether the parameters ur passing is correct  or not (it could be parameter names , or any extra params).